# A question on determining the contrapositive of a statement.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm having a hard time understanding the concept of a contrapostive of a given statement.

For example, let's consider the statement:
**If** $a$ and $b$ are odd, **then** $ab$ is odd.

We know it's of the form: **If** $A$, **then** $B$

Then, its contrapositive is : **if** $notB$, **then** $notA$.

Hence, the required contrapositive is: **If** $ab$ is not odd, **then** $a$ and $b$ are not odd.

However, the question I'm doing does not seem to consider this as the right answer.

Could anyone, please, point out what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The contrapositive should be:

**If** $ab$ is not odd, **then** it is not true that both $a$ and $b$ are odd

It not being true that both $a$ and $b$ are odd is not the same as $a$ and $b$ both not being odd

Consider: It is true that $3$ and $4$ are not both odd, but it is false that $3$ and $4$ are both not odd.

In short: 'not both' is not the same as 'both not'

Comment: Cheers. If you don't mind me asking, why's that so?

Comment: @SxS You can compare the truth-table of $\neg (P \land Q)$ and $\neg P \land \neg Q$ and find them to be different. But just intuitively, and as applied to this case: if it is not true that both $a$ and $b$ are odd, then it could still be true that one of them is odd, and so that's not the same as both of them not being odd, which rules out that possibility. Or even more concretely: it is true that $3$ and $4$ are not both odd, but it is false that $3$ and $4$ are both not odd.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Then in other word, this contrapositive is logically equivalent to the statement: if $ab$ is even, then at least one of $a$ and  $b$ is even.

Comment: @SxS Correct!  The 'if' part was a conjunction, and so when you apply the contrapositive, you get the negation of that conjunction as the consequent, which by DeMorgan is a disjunction of the two parts negated.